# Does makeObjectsPerformSelector: always happen on the main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have a line of code using`makeObjectsPerformSelector:`

```
[view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]
```

in my project . Does this always happen on the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. Methods will run **on the thread where they're invoked** unless otherwise specified by their docs. Compare [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414900-performselectoronmainthread) and [`performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1417922-performselector)